# How can I click on image using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to log in a webpage using PowerShell, but the 'Sign In' button is coded like this:

```
<input type="image" src="http://tolimages.traderonline.com/i... alt="Sign In">
```

What function should I use in PowerShell to be able to click on the picture and therefore, log in?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

***Try this:***

```
$url = "http://xxxxxxxxxx/"
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate($url)
While ($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 400 }
$Link = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object {$_.type -eq "image"}
$Link.click();
```